# Google Maps Services Java Client Freezing WebApp

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to get the latitude and longitude of a location name entered by a customer from the Google Places API. The excecution freezes at the second line.

```
    try {
            GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("MY_API_KEY").build();
            PlaceDetails placeDetails = PlacesApi.placeDetails(context, "Nairobi").await();
            double lat = placeDetails.geometry.location.lat;
            double lng = placeDetails.geometry.location.lng;
        } catch (ApiException | InterruptedException | IOException apiException) {
        apiException.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

I get the following stack trace but I can't quite pinout the root cause as the example I am running is the simplest in the tests provided.

**Libraries included in my application are:**

1. google-maps-services-0.2.1.jar
2. gson-2.8.1.jar
3. okhttp-3.8.1.jar
4. okio-1.13.0.jar
5. slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

**This is also a [similar issue on github](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/287)**

This is the stack trace I gate and

```
Info:   apartments was successfully deployed in 2,737 milliseconds.
Severe:   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Severe:   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Severe:   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Severe:   Exception in thread "RateLimitExecutorDelayThread"
Severe:   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire()D
    at com.google.maps.internal.RateLimitExecutorService.run(RateLimitExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: could you solve it?

Comment: @TimSchwalbe yes I was finally able to solve it. I used the older version because the google API version 0.2.1 has a threading problem. https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/287#issuecomment-321938011

Answer (score 0):

Change Google API Version to 0.2.0 as below in pom.xml
`<dependency>`
    `<groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>`
    `<artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>`
    `<version>0.2.0</version>`
''

This will fix your problem